# mySQL INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY - no idea whats not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert-into, on-duplicate-key

I just tried to get an INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY mySQL query to get to work. Unfortunately with no luck.
I read all the many posts on that matter here in stackoverflow, I had a look at this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html, but still no luck...

I have a table like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| id | option1 | option 2 | option 3 | option 4 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 83 |    0     |    1     |     0    |    0    |
```

My Id is a Unique value, but not Auto Incrementing.
all other values are booleans describing some chosen options.

I wanted to write a function to either update the table if the id is already existing or write a new row if I have a new id.

I'm working with existing code with a database class.

```
$this->db = new PDO($host, $user, $password);
$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
```

(don't ask me about the setAttribute. That's just what was in the Code...)
and later on:

```
$this->query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable (id, option1, option2, option3, option4) 
VALUES (83, 0, 1, 1, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = VALUES(id)");
$this->query->execute();
```

I know that I don't really have to prepare anything like binds. (In the end I want to do so, but I could not figure out how to get it done here.

Well I don't get any error Message from catching PDO Exceptions but I cannot get my database updated.
Let's assume that all the stuff concerning connecting to the DB is ok (as I can select data).

I also tried notations like this:

```
$this->query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable (id, option1, option2, option3, option4) 
VALUES (83, 0, 1, 1, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = 83");
```

or

```
$this->query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable (id, option1, option2, option3, option4) 
VALUES (83, 0, 1, 1, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = id + 1");
```

Which would all be the same, right?

Well, I would be very very glad if someone could help me out here. I must be doing something completely wrong...

Comment: Do you have a unique index on the table?

Comment: Yes, as I said. My Id column is unique.

Comment: If I use a query that looks like this if I print it ```$this->sql = "INSERT INTO user_company_options (`id`, `option1`) VALUES (`id` = :id, `option1` = :option1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE option1 = VALUES(option1);";``` I end up with a database row with Id = 0 and option 1 = 1. I think I'm still confusing something. (To mention that this query now has bind options which I also bind in a later statement.
I found out that the duplicate key probably does my 'id = VALUES(id)' and changed it to option1 = VALUES(option1). At least I see some changes done in my DB but still not the right ones ...

Answer (score 2):

You don't want `on duplicate key update`.  This either inserts a *new* row.  Or it updates the old row.  You seem to want to insert a new row, but with a different id when there is a conflict.

I might suggest something like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(id, option1, option2, option3, option4) 
    select (case when max(id = 83) > 0 then max(id) + 1
                 else 83
            end), 0, 1, 1, 1
    from mytable;
```

This will put `83` into the table if it does not exist.  It will put the maximum `id` + 1 in if `83` does exist.

I don't *really* recommend this.  Better you should have an auto-incrementing id.  I don't think the above logic is multi-user safe in all storage engines, but it might solve your problem.

Comment: Well thanks for the help. I figured it out... I used:
$this->sql = "INSERT INTO myTable ('id', 'option1') VALUES (83, 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE option1 = VALUES(option1)";
Which was actually practically the code I had before your answer. I just made a mistake in the first bracket-section.
With this code I have an update on option1 where my id is 83, if id 83 does no exist, I get an insert. Think it's quite okay.
As I wanted to insert OR update, that's exactly what I wanted...